# Надо ли удалять объект Runnable()?

Tags: java, android, android-threads

Есть метод с кодом

```
SomeActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
    ........
    }
});
```

Не ясно следующее: что происходит с объектом класса `Runnable()`, который создаётся в `new`. Точнее, когда он удаляется, и удаляется ли вообще до завершения приложения? Если это описано в документации, просьба дать ссылку. Я не смог найти.

Comment: Нет, не нужно, никто не удаляет, вообще в Java сборка мусора есть, почему именно по нему возникли вопросы.

Comment: Потому что если я в приложении много раз произвожу подобные действия - мне не ясно что происходит с этими объектами. Не ясно - когда именно они становятся мусором. Или не становятся, и эти объекты постепенно пожирают оперативную память. Или же, как должно быть по логике, этот объект становится мусором после того, как его поток завершится. Но я не нашёл чёткое описание.

Comment: Вроде так - при отсутствии ссылок на объект он удаляется при следующем проходе GC. Который может произойти когда угодно. Чаще всего когда в куче заканчивается место

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java объекты удаляются сборщиком мусора, если на них никто не ссылается. Разберёмся кто и когда ссылается на ваш `Runnable`.

Внутри потока пользовательского интерфейса крутится [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). Грубо говоря, это бесконечный цикл, на каждой итерации достающий и обрабатывающий *сообщения* из [MessageQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html). Когда ваш поток вызывает метод `runOnUiThread`, переданный в этот метод `Runnable` добавляется в очередь. Пока `Runnable` находится в очереди, она хранит на него ссылку. В какой-то момент, `Looper` извлекает `Runnable` из очереди и сохраняет в локальной переменной. Теперь `Looper` хранит ссылку на `Runnable`. `Looper` вызывает метод `run` и ждёт его завершения. После завершения этого метода, `Looper` начнёт новую итерацию, уничтожив все локальные переменные, в том числе ссылку на `Runnable`. При следующем запуске сборщик мусора обнаружит, что на этот `Runnable` нет ссылок и уничтожит его.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это мне и нужно было узнать.

Comment: @Gourmand [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)